# Residue of $\frac{1}{z(e^{z}-1)}$

Tags: complex-analysis, residue-calculus

I was trying to find the residue of   $\dfrac {1}{z (e^z - 1)}$. I have written the Taylor series for $e^z$ which is $1 + z + \dfrac{z^2}{2!} + \dfrac{z^3}{3!}..$ Thus, for $e^z - 1$ I have series of the form $z+\dfrac{z^2}{2!}+\dfrac{z^3}{3!}..$. But now I am stuck as I have a problem dividing 1 with my series.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> We obtain
>   \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{\frac{1}{z\left(e^z-1\right)}}&=\frac{1}{z(z+\frac{1}{2}z^2+O(z^3))}\tag{1}\\
> &=\frac{1}{z^2\left(1+\frac{1}{2}z+O(z^2)\right)}\tag{2}\\
> &=\frac{1}{z^2}\left(1-\frac{1}{2}z+O(z^2)\right)\tag{3}\\
> &\,\,\color{blue}{=\frac{1}{z^2}-\frac{1}{2z}+O(1)}
> \end{align*}
>   and we conclude the residue is $\color{blue}{-\frac{1}{2}}$.

*Comment:*

- In (1) we expand $e^z-1$ up to $z^3$.
- In (2) we factor out $z$.
- In (3) we do a geometric series expansion
  \begin{align*}
  \frac{1}{z^2\left(1+\frac{1}{2}z+O(z^2)\right)}&=\frac{1}{z^2}\left(1-\left(\frac{1}{2}z+O(z^2)\right)-\left(\frac{1}{2}z+O(z^2)\right)^2+O(z^2)\right)\\
  &=\frac{1}{z^2}\left(1-\frac{1}{2}z+O(z^2)\right)
  \end{align*}

Comment: I believe in second step factoring out z we would have $z^2(1+\dfrac{1}{2}z+O(z^2)$ and I still don't understand the step in between 2 and 3. Could you believe explain it in more details :)

Comment: It's a geometric series $1/(1- w) = 1 + w + w^2 + \dots$ for $|w|<1$. Markus sets $w=-(\frac12z^2 + O(z^3))$.

Comment: @GGphys: Typo corrected, thanks. I've added some info in the comment which might be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to find the residue is using one of the well known residue formulas.

We have

- $e^z-1$ has a zero of order 1 at $z=0$
- $\Rightarrow \frac{1}{z(e^z-1)}$ has a pole of order 2 at $z= 0$
- $\Rightarrow Res_0 \frac{1}{z(e^z-1)} = \lim_{z\rightarrow 0}\frac{d}{dz}\left(z^2\frac{1}{z(e^z-1)} \right)= \lim_{z\rightarrow 0}\frac{d}{dz}\frac{z}{e^z-1} = \lim_{z\rightarrow 0} \frac{e^z-1 - ze^z}{e^{2z}-2e^z+1}$
- Note that $\frac{z}{e^z-1}$ has a removable singularity at $z=0$ and the limit of its first derivative at $z=0$ exists. So, we can use L'Hospital to calculate the limit:
  $$Res_0 \frac{1}{z(e^z-1)}=\lim_{z\rightarrow 0} \frac{e^z-1 - ze^z}{e^{2z}-2e^z+1} = \lim_{z\rightarrow 0} \frac{-ze^z}{2e^{2z}-2e^z}=\lim_{z\rightarrow 0} \frac{-z}{2e^{z}-2} =\lim_{z\rightarrow 0} \frac{-1}{2e^{z}}= -\frac{1}{2}$$